# Find active window with VBS script

Tags: desktop, vbscript, window-focus, refresh

I need to auto-refresh the desktop every 10 minutes.

The only full-working way I found is using this VBS code.

`Sh.AppActivate "Program Manager"`

`Sh.SendKeys("{F5}")`

But in this way the active window becomes the Desktop.

I need to re-activate the focus on the window I am using before the script starts.

Comment: I feel like this may be an XY Problem. Why do you feel that you need to refresh the desktop every 10 minutes?

Comment: It's long to explain. It's an important part of a debug process to test a more complex batch program.

Comment: "It's long to explain" makes it hard for someone to put in the effort of coming up with a good answer.

Comment: I can't be more exact, sorry. I just need to do it for debug purposes.

Comment: You should check out AutoHotkey. It http://ahkscript.org/. It makes any kind of ui automation simple.

Answer (score 1):

I found a trick to solve the problem:

at the and of the script, add the command line:

```
Sh.SendKeys("%{ESC}")
```

It re-activates the focus on the window I was using before the script started.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to re-activate the focus on the window I am using before the script starts.

- Capture the current window (title or PID) using a COM wrapper.

For instructions on that, see StackOverflow: [How to find the window Title of Active(foreground) window using Window Script Host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26341753/how-to-find-the-window-title-of-activeforeground-window-using-window-script-ho)

- Record it to a variable.
- Activate the desktop.
- Refresh.
- Return focus to recorded window using the variable's contents.